# access t9 predictive text input engine on Android phones

Tags: android

I was wondering it there is an API that can access the core functionality of t9 predictive text engine on Android phones.
The API should have some access point like:
-setCurrentLanguage
-closeCurrentLanguage
-appendKey(some key)
For example: appendKey(4),appendKey(6),appendKey(6),appendKey(3) will give: "good"
-get current word
-get next candidate
-get previous candidate etc...
In Symbian it is called CPtiEngine.

Thanks for help